# Difference between render functions in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to understand the difference between the different `render` functions in Phoenix. Specifically, I notice there are several different `render` functions in a Phoenix View and a Phoenix Template.

For example, within a Phoenix Controller, it's common to see something like this:

```
# assume this is UserController
def index(conn, _params) do
    users = Repo.all(Users) # let's assume that this gives you all your users
    render conn, "index.html", users: users
end
```

Within the `index.html` template associated with this View (i.e. UserView), you can see something like this:

```
# index.html
<ul>
    <%= for user <- @users do %>
        <li><%= render "user.html", user: user %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>

# user.html
<p><%= @user.name %></p>
```

My understanding is that the `render` function inside of the `index.html` template is compiled to a `render` function inside of the `UserView`. Also, after digging around in `iex`, it seems like the `render` function in the `UserController`'s index action comes from `Phoenix.Controller.render/3`.

**However, I notice that inside of the default `app.html.eex` template file, there's a render function that looks like this:**

```
<%= render @view_module, @view_template, assign %>
```

**This doesn't seem to match the signatures of the previous render functions. Can anyone help explain where this render is coming from and how it works?**

Answer (score 1):

[`Phoenix.View`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html) has a descriptive documentation, and if still in doubt, there is a source code for [`Phoenix.View.render/3`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/5b9bb2b37a133c1aaf3b5289e53869ab20d076b9/lib/phoenix/view.ex#L179) and [`Phoenix.Controller.render/{1,3,4}`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/f557b757fb361b18ff45d8255aa3b1fb059439a8/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L576) on hand.

The related quote from the documentation:

> This inner representation allows us to render and compose templates easily. For example, if you want to render JSON data, we could do so by adding a “show.json” entry to render/2 in our view:
>
> ```
> defmodule YourApp.UserView do
>   use YourApp.View    
>   def render("show.json", %{user: user}) do
>     %{name: user.name, address: user.address}
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question, just links to the documentation and sources. (Perusing all the resources linked would indeed provide one with the answer, and they are indeed freely accessible, but then 95% of the questions of this site could be answered with a template.)

Answer (score 1):

The `Phoenix.Controller.render/4` is passed the conn struct which picks up a number of things like overriding the layout, the view, plash messages, assigns, etc. So, you will see render called that way in controllers.

The `render "templ.html", opts` version renders the template of the same View of the caller. This can be used from a template to render a partial.

The `Phoenix.View.render App.MyView, "templ.html", opts` is used to render a template from a different view. That is why its called that way from the layout template.

They all end up calling the `App.MyView.render/2`. If you have templates then those functions will exist. But you can create your own render function in the view and call it as was pointed out in the answer with the json example.